# Testing if a Double is an Integral value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list areas :: [Double]. Now I want to filter this list for those which are actually integral values. I want to do something like this for my predicate:

```
isInteger :: Double -> Bool
isInteger x = abs (fromIntegral (floor x) - x) < delta
  where delta = 0.00001
```

However, I would guess there is a better way to do this. Is there a Haskell idiom for checking if a real value is an integer?

Comment: @pst My usage of the word integral is correct: "5. Arithmetic. pertaining to or being an integer; not fractional." Of course, it can be confused with a second mathematical definition from calculus: "8. Mathematics. a. Also called Riemann integral. the numerical measure of the area bounded above by the graph of a given function, below by the x -axis, and on the sides by ordinates drawn at the endpoints of a specified interval;" (both definitions come from Dictionary.com)

Comment: Apologies, now I wonder what in heck I *was* looking up last week ... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks fine and idiomatic to me, though you probably want to use `round` rather than `floor`. You could also consider using [`approxRational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html#v%3aapproxRational) and checking that the denominator of the result is `1`:

```
isInteger x = denominator (approxRational x 0.00001) == 1
```

Comment: This looks a little more Haskell-like to me. Thanks! Also, I found a minor error in my original version. Since floor returns an Integral type, I had to add fromIntegral in order to do the subtraction. Finally, I agree that round would probably be better because something like 1.999999999 is basically 2.